# make margin fixed on both sides (left/right)

Tags: css, margin

How can I keep the margin size fixed on both sides even after decreasing the viewport?

So that only the image size decrease.

before decreasing viewport:

[image: before decreasing viewport]

after decreasing viewport:

[image: after decreasing viewport]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(480px, 33.3vw) 33.3vw 33.3vw;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

.text {
    background-color: #6544d9;
    grid-column: 1;
}

.image {
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vKiZ.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    margin: 100px;

}
```

```html
    <section class="text"></section>
    <section class="image"></section>
```

Comment: margin: auto perhaps?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Its tough to say exactly what the issue is with what you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Percent (%) and rem are both relative units, but px is an absolute unit. The phrasing of your question was a little confusing but if you want the margin to stay the absolute same width, use px for the margin. If you want the margin to automatically adapt to the size of the viewport, use the % or rem, both of which refer to the relative size of an element to its root.

Comment: I want to make the image adapt to the viewport size while the margin stays the same